# Pre-fill fields with query parameter using form's URL

Tags: cognito-forms

Same question as [Cognito Forms: pre-fill field with query parameter](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/73473/cognito-forms-pre-fill-field-with-query-parameter) but by passing parameters in the form's URL.

Comment: So just to clarify, you want to prefill a form that is not embedded, but instead is accessed using the [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) share link?

Comment: Exactly! I tried to add ?FieldName1=value&FieldName2=value at the end of the URL, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Any suggestion since I replied?

Comment: This is not currently supported and we are trying to decide whether to add support now as a hotfix or schedule this for our next feature release.

Comment: Feature now available. Thanks!