# Is there a way to incorporate the Registered users into Cognito Forms?

Tags: cognito-forms

For Example: Someone submits a form to me, would be nice to see which Registered user did the submission. Currently the situation that bugs me is as follows:
My Users already logged in to my site, where the email address and his name was already part of the registration process. Now I want him to submit his request via a Cognito Form, it is kind of irritating for the user to go and fill in his info again whilst the site already knows it.

If I'm thinking like a user, I will automatically feel "But don't you have my information already"?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

If you are embedding the form into your site, please reference this [Stack Exchange Question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/73473/cognito-forms-pre-fill-field-with-query-parameter) for pre-filling data on a Cognito Form.  It outlines how to update the embed code to handle pre-filling form data.

Currently the embed strategy is the only method that supports pre-filling form data. There is a card on our [Public Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/m07KaM4l) for supporting query string parameters being passed via the public link, but the feature is not currently supported.