# Pre Fille Certain Fields

Tags: cognito-forms

I have no understanding of scripts and I am not very technical.

I am looking to pre populate form 2 using information from form 1.

IE - When a customer fills in our basic form with name etc I then want to direct them to a second form in which we ask for a lot more information. On this second form, I would like the name, company email, email address fields auto populated using the inform they put into form 1.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do this depending on how you are building your application.  This answer is assuming you are building both forms as a multi-page form within CognitoForms.

Say you have a form consisting of a single field "Name" on the form.  Now you add a page break so that you have a second page where you want to collect more information such as email and address.

Add a second field "Name" here and on the settings click on the "Default Value" field.  In that default value field, enter an "=" sign and then you can select the Name filed from page 1 from a dropdown.

So at this point, the customer enters their name on page 1, clicks next, and on page 2 sees their name already filled out along with the additional fields such as email and address.

If you are actually using two different forms, it's a bit more complicated but you can pre-fill the fields with the query parameter - see [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/73473/cognito-forms-pre-fill-field-with-query-parameter).